# How to align bootstrap button to the left while resizing browser - mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just a small problem. 
I have this code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:580px;"></a>
```

The button is in the center of the page and when I am resizing the browser, the text above is nicely narrowing and fitting into the smaller screen size. However, the button stays in the same place, and when I come to the breakpoint of a smartphone - it doesn't show up at all.

How do I align/move the button in order to show it in the center, below the text, on a small screen?

Comment: remove the margin-left and use media queries.. If you can post the html and css we can help further..

Answer (score 0):

Your `style` is not dynamic.

If you want the button centered horizontally try instead: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

If this isn't what you are after please update your question with your CSS and HTML so we can get more context.

Answer (score 0):

It will stay in the same place since you specified the `style=margin-left`

You either set it to `auto` as well as margin-right to `auto` to keep it in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions to center the button on the page:

1) Change the "margin-left:580px;" to a "%" value of "margin-left:50%"

2) Use flex-box and put the "a" tag inside a div that has the following CSS:
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

```css
.container-for-button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Old Button-->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:580px;">Lorum</a>

<br />

<!--Solution 1-->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:50%">Lorum</a>

<br />

<!--Solution 2-->
<div class="container-for-button">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:0 auto; ">Lorum</a>
</div>
```